# C# How to resolve DNS through a proxy?

Tags: c#, .net, networking, proxy, dns

I meet a trouble called *Domain Pollution* or *DNS Cache Poisoning*, so I wanna resolve the Urls to ip addresses through a proxy. I set the system proxy and using the C# code below:

```
Dns.GetHostEntry("example.com").AddressList[0].ToString();
```

But It still return a polluted ip, the same as a ping command return. I guess it didn't go through the proxy. So how should I resolve DNS through a proxy in C#?

(Environment: Windows 11, .Net5)

Comment: I studied some open-source DNS Resolvers' codes. They use **HttpClient.PostAsync()** to send DNS resolving messages to DNS servers. None of them use **Dns.GetHostEntry()**. I guess **Dns.GetHostEntry()** maybe just use icmp like what a ping command do. So it cannot go through the proxy.

Comment: I think Microsoft must alse have other functions resolving DNS not with icmp

Answer (score 1):

can you try this:

```
DnsUtils.FlushCache("example.com"); 

public class DnsUtils  
{        
    [DllImport("dnsapi.dll", EntryPoint="DnsFlushResolverCache")]
    static extern UInt32 DnsFlushResolverCache();

    [DllImport("dnsapi.dll", EntryPoint = "DnsFlushResolverCacheEntry_A")]
    public static extern int DnsFlushResolverCacheEntry(string hostName);

    public static void FlushCache()
    {
        DnsFlushResolverCache();
    }

    public static void FlushCache(string hostName)
    {
        DnsFlushResolverCacheEntry(hostName);
    }
}
```

solution from : [BRIAN MANCINI - System.Net.Dns Flush Cache Issues](https://www.derpturkey.com/system-net-dns-flush-cache-issues/)

Comment: it doesnt work for me